# ¿Cómo ajustar el tamaño de un PDF generado desde PHP y hacer un ticket?

Tags: javascript, php, mpdf

Estoy haciendo un sistema que genera un comprobante este comprobante esta en `PDF`, lo que necesito es ajustar el tamaño del `PDF` en un ticket no en `A4` como viene predeterminado, estoy usando la libreria `dompdf`, pero si pueden ayudarme quizá con otra libreria o como ajustar el tamaño del papel que genera el `PDF` para que tenga las dimensiones de un ticket, me seria de mucha ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
Por favor, proporciona un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Para mejorar tus oportunidades de obtener respuestas, [sigue estos consejos para mejorar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Usa

```
//Tamaño personalizado
$dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0,500,1000));
```

[Fuente](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage)

Comment: Gracias, me sirve de mucho

Comment: Con la ultima versión de DOMPDF debe de ser $dompdf->setPaper pero eso no arregla el problema.. debes de ajustar tu table y reducir el tamaño de letra.

Comment: pues si, si sirvio asi, al menos para mi, no tuve que modificar tablas ni nada

Comment: aunque para hacer tickets es mejor usar fpdf, ya que para un ticket no hay necesidad de mucho diseño solo organizar el orden de la informacion y tienen unos ejemplos para ese caso y es mucho mas rapido configurarlo para eso especificamente, si es para hacer ya formatos mas complejos en diseño si es mejor dompdf, es solo ver la herramienta adecuada en cada caso